# PRA: Rare event approximation with $P(A\cup B \cup \neg C)$?

Tags: probability, risk-assessment

The rare event approximation for event $A$ and $B$ means the upper-bound approximation $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)+P(B)$. Now by inclusion-exclusion-principle $$P(A\cup B\cup \neg C)= P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap \neg C) -P(B\cap\neg C) +P(A\cap B\cap \neg  C) \leq P(A)+P(B)+P(C)+P(A\cap B\cap \neg  C)$$

and now by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), this is the general form

[image]

so **does the rare-event-approximation means removal of minus terms in the general form of inclusion-exclusion principle aka the below?**

$$\mathbb P\left(\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right)\leq \sum_{I\subset\{1,3,...,2h-1\}; |I|=k}\mathbb P(A_I)$$

where $2h-1$ is the last odd term in $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$.

**Example**

> For example in the case of three events, is the below true rare-event
>   approximation?
>
> $$P(A\cup B\cup \neg C) \leq P(A)+P(B)+P(\neg C)+P(A\cap B\cap \neg  C)$$

*P.s. I am studying probability-risk-assessment course, [Mat-2.3117](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-2.3117).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing **all** the negatives certainly gives an upper bound. But if one looks at the logic of the inclusion-exclusion argument, **whenever** we have just added, we have added too much (except possibly, at the very end). So at any stage just before we start subtracting again, our truncated expression gives an upper bound.

Thus one obtains upper bounds by truncating after the first sum, or the third, or the fifth, and so on.

Comment: Do you mean the rare-event approximation for $P(A\cup B\cup C)$ with the three events is not unique i.e. I can approximate the original expressions in multiple ways by removing between one and all minus terms?

Comment: There is  $\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)+\Pr(C)$, and of course the full absolutely correct three-term expression, which is not really an approximation. Things get more interesting at, say, $5$ terms, where we can stop after $\sum \Pr(A_i)$, or $\sum \Pr(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k)$ (or at the end, but then we are not really approximating).  Note that your approximation around the third line is unduly pessimistic, you don't want to add the $\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)$ term.

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand your point about the addition $Pr(A\cap B\cap\neg C)$: why not add it? Is it still an upper bound for the event if you don't have it there? -Of course because $Pr(A\cap B\cap \neg C)\leq Pr(A\cap B)+Pr(A\cap\neg C)+Pr(B\cap \neg C)$, right? This is the reason for the pessimism?

Comment: Yes, it is still an upper bound without that term. Of course you can add it, but there is no point in doing extra work to get a worse result.

Comment: Yes it makes sense but how to generalize this observation? See my update in the earlier comment: I think I understood your meaning, I am trying to think what is the least upper bound. Is the least upper bound called *"rare-event approximation"* also? Or does the *"rare event approximation"* only mean the least upper bound for the system? I haven't seen a formal definition of this term...

Comment: The least upper bound is the exact answer. We want an easy to compute upper bound. In surprisingly many cases, $\sum \Pr(A_i)$ is good enough.  When it isn't, $\sum \Pr(A_i)-\sum\Pr(A_i\cap A_j)+\sum\Pr(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k)$ is often good enough. One may even have to go two steps further.

Comment: By two steps further, do you mean the following? $$\sum \Pr(A_i)-\sum\Pr(A_i\cap A_j)+\sum\Pr(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k)-\sum\Pr(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k\cap A_l)+\sum\Pr(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k\cap A_l\cap A_m)$$

Do I understand correctly that the rare-event approximation means the least upper bound? But more pessimistic forms of rare-event approximation can contain more addition terms? I don't yet understand the essence of this approximation: I read online that this can be used only in certain circumstances when probabilities are small but I did not understand it all. If some book,  I am very happy!

Comment: Yes, by two steps further I mean what you wrote. The approximation is useful when individual probabilities are smallish, so that probabilities of long intersections are very small.

Comment: And if you want to simplify the approximation you can do simple taylor series approximation for the tail with respect some term assuming the terms in the tail are small? Is this correct? Suppose $Pr(S)=e^{-\lambda t}$. Now you can do the linear polynomial approximation without even looking for terms in the tail if you know the terms in the tail are small? (I read some books in Google Books and it looks this is the reason they use the linearization approximation, it simplifies calculations) Thank you for your answer! +1

Comment: That's another kind of rare event approximation. It comes up when one is doing the theory of the relationship between the exponential, the Poisson, and the binomial when $np$ is "small." We end up assuming that in a small amount of time $\Delta t$, the probability of two or more events is negligible.